# How to disable sorbs in spamassassin

Tags: email, postfix, centos6, spamassassin

I notice that sorbs.net is marking GMail's IP as spam sender which causes my users not able to receive from gmail.com. I want to disable or remove sorbs.net from checking process or add more DNSBLs in order let gmail emails in. 
I tried adding the following to my `local.cf` but no success:

```
whitelist_from_rcvd  *@gmail.com  gmail.com
score   __RCVD_IN_SORBS  0
```

I also tried to comment/delete sorbs from `20_dnsbl_tests.cf`  but it didn't do anything either.

Here's the log from maillog:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-oi0-f48.google.com[209.85.218.48]: 
454 4.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.218.48] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; 
Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.218.48; 
from=<someone@gmail.com> to=<email@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-oi0-f48.google.com>
Sep  3 15:03:05 server postfix/smtpd[16891]: disconnect from mail-oi0-f48.google.com[209.85.218.48]
```

Answer (score 2):

As from SpamAssassin version 3.4 you may disable queries for any BL by adding: (local.cf)

```
dns_query_restriction deny sorbs.net
```

Comment: I already tried that, No success.

Comment: The last reasonable assumption is that you have edited not the effective configs. May be you have configured SA to be launched with some non-implicit  config files.

Comment: I posted the answer to my problem. See my own answer.

Comment: At least I was right and you have edited the wrong config.

Comment: Yeah, fault was mine. your answer would solve normal situation.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it was postfix that was doing the checking not SpamAssassin. If you encounter the same problem, open your `main.cf` file (probably in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`) and find the line that starts with `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`  and remove `reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net`  from it.